# Is it possible to make the lock screen's background a feed from the front-facing camera?

Tags: 22.04, security, lock-screen, camera

People tend to behave better when they know they're being watched, even by a machine. To deter people screwing with my desk, is it possible to have the lock screen background be a (blurred) camera feed?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jeffshee/hidamari set to an URL of another ffmpeg process streaming the video from the camera?